# Error while building the project, package org.springframework.boot.test.web.client doesn't exists. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am getting the following error while building the project:

`package org.springframework.boot.test.web.client doesn't exists`

What dependency should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following starter to you `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

As you can see in its [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-test/pom.xml#L24) it includes `spring-boot-test` which has the package [`/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client) available for you.

Comment: I already have that in my pom file, but still getting the error at compile time

Comment: And you are sure, that the artifact `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test` is in your libs?

Comment: Could you please share a piece of source code, where you encounter this message?